# No overload for method 'GetRows()' takes one argument

Tags: sql, asp.net, layer

I am developing a view page.

Here is my code:

```
int idses = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());

// address
DataTable adrDT = new DataTable();
adrDT = ClassView.GetRows(idses);

houseN.Text = adrDT.Rows[0]["houseN"].ToString();
streetAD.Text = adrDT.Rows[0]["stAddress"].ToString();
townAD.Text = adrDT.Rows[0]["town"].ToString();
cityAD.Text = adrDT.Rows[0]["city"].ToString();
stateAD.Text = adrDT.Rows[0]["state"].ToString();
zipC.Text = adrDT.Rows[0]["zipCOde"].ToString();
ddlC.SelectedValue = adrDT.Rows[0]["countryID"].ToString();
teleNumb.Text = adrDT.Rows[0]["telephoneN"].ToString();
faxNumb.Text = adrDT.Rows[0]["faxN"].ToString();
```

this the code in my datalayer:

```
string rowSQL = "SELECT Merchant_Master.id, Merchant_Master.CompanyName, Merchant_Master.Url, Merchant_Master.AddressID, Industry.IndustryName, "
              + "Merchant_Master.IsActive, Merchant_Master.IsDeleted, Merchant_Master.DateCreated "
              + "FROM Merchant_Master JOIN Industry on Merchant_Master.IndustryID = Industry.id where Merchant_Master.id = @id";
//string rowSQL = "SELECT CompanyName, Url, DateCreated FROM Merchant_Master";

string[] param = {"@id"};
object[] paramVal = {};

return ClassDBQuery.ExecDataReader(rowSQL, param, paramVal);
```

My question is: How will I call the @id in the code behind?

`adrDT = ClassView.GetRows(idses);` -> in this line...when I put idses, I get the error "No overload for method 'GetRows()' takes one argument"... What should I do?

Comment: @carth maybe you can help me again...:)

Answer (score 0):

This means that, on your ClassView class, you dont have a GetRows method expecting any parameter. Look your ClassView again.

EDIT:

If the type of idses is int, you should do:

```
public static DataTable GetRows(int ideses) {...}
```

Comment: i declared my getrow method like this 
public static DataTable GetRows().. i need to put parameters inside it..? #___#

Comment: public static DataTable GetRows(int idses)
        {
            sqlquery.....

            string[] param = {"@id"};
            object[] paramVal = {idses};

            return ClassDBQuery.ExecDataReader(rowSQL, param, paramVal);

so it will be like this..?

Comment: @aianLee, the problem of your initial post will be solved if you change the GetRows method like i said. I really dont know about your ClassDBQuery.ExecDataReader and what you need to pass to this method.

Comment: yeah...sorry..i just realized that i was tweaking the method for gridview databinding...i created a new method and it works..thanks though.. @jhonatas kleinkauff